# Solve the problem of dividing the field into two parts, one for the icon and one for writing

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I have this code and it is in order to distribute tasks to employees and I have a form for logging in and it contains several text fields and each field has an icon and a place to fill in the field, but the problem is as it appears in the picture, which is the presence of a barrier between the place of writing and the icon in each field.

That is, as it is clear in the picture, there is a place that has a blue color, and the place of the icon does not contain anything.

How can I solve this problem?

code.tsx:

```js
const LoginFirebase: FC = (props) => {
  const isMountedRef = useIsMountedRef();
  const { user, loginUserWithEmailAndPassword, loginError } = useAuthModule(
    (state) => state
  );
  console.log('this is the user from the state 1 from Reg-Com: ', user);
  const navigation = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      console.log('logged in user: ', user);
      navigation('/dashboard');
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        sx={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          display: 'flex',
        }}
      ></Box>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          email: '',
          password: '',
          submit: null,
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
          email: Yup.string()
            .email('Must be a valid email')
            .max(255)
            .required('Email is required'),
          password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required'),
        })}
        onSubmit={async (
          values,
          { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }
        ): Promise<void> => {
          try {
            await loginUserWithEmailAndPassword(values);

            if (isMountedRef.current) {
              setStatus({ success: true });
              setSubmitting(false);
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            if (isMountedRef.current) {
              setStatus({ success: false });
              setErrors({ submit: err.message });
              setSubmitting(false);
            }
          }
        }}
      >
        {({
          errors,
          handleBlur,
          handleChange,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting,
          touched,
          values,
        }): JSX.Element => (
          <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <DraftsOutlinedIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
              error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
              helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.email}
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              fullWidth
              margin="normal"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              variant="outlined"
            />
            <TextField
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <LockOutlinedIcon />
                  </InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
              placeholder="Enter password"
              error={Boolean(touched.password && errors.password)}
              helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.password}
              fullWidth
              margin="normal"
              name="password"
              type="password"
              variant="outlined"
            />
            {errors.submit && (
              <Box sx={{ mt: 3 }}>
                <FormHelperText error>{errors.submit}</FormHelperText>
              </Box>
            )}
            <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
              <Button
                style={{
                  marginTop: '1rem',
                  maxHeight: '3.4rem',
                  minHeight: '3.4rem',
                }}
                color="primary"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                fullWidth
                size="large"
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
              >
                Log in
              </Button>
            </Box>
            {loginError && <p>{loginError}</p>}
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginFirebase;
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this?

Comment: my code is clear and short....my problem just in text fields

Comment: 90% of your code has nothing to do with the text field appearance and it's not clear how and where you applied your styling

Comment: In that case, best of luck. Should be super easy for someone to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The `Textfield` is most likely a parent [flex](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) `div` that contains 2 child flex `div` elements: one `div` for the icon and one `div` for the input. It appears that the light-blue background is only being applied to the child input field when it has been focused. Unfortunately, it's not as simple as moving the light-blue background to the parent `div` because the parent won't know when one of its children has been focused.

#### Solution

You'll need to leverage the [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) CSS property, which will change the parent `div` CSS when a child element has been focused.

### Demo

[image: Edit Custom Input Component]

### Other thoughts

Another approach would be to avoid using `flex` and instead have the `input` take up the entire field while the icon hovers over it using [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) `absolute`:

[image: Edit Custom Input Component (input as entire field)]